# Copying vector<string> data into struct data member in C++

Tags: c++, stl

This is my struct:

```
typedef struct
{

    string uiVersionNumber;

    unsigned long uiTimeStamp;

}Req_Port;
```

The vector is defined like this:

```
std::vector<string> colIndex;
```

The *colIndex* contains vector of strings. Say the 3rd element here is the *uiVersionNumber* data. How do I copy the 3rd element which is a string to the struct member *uiVersionNumber* which is also of string datatype.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Req_Port.uiVersionNumber = colIndex[3];`?

Comment: Lets simplify this a little, lets say you have two normal local variables, like `s1` and `s2`, defined like `std::string s1, s2;`. How would you copy the value from `s1` into `s2`? What makes you think using an array element as source would be different from `s1`? Or why it would be different by using a member variable from a structure instead of the variable `s2`?

Comment: There’s no need for this `typedef struct …` thing. It’s a C-ism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access elements of a vector like in a C-array or use the `at()` method of `vector`

So you can do:

```
Req_Port.uiVersionNumber = colIndex.at(2);
// Req_Port.uiVersionNumber = colIndex[2]; does not check for out-of-bound errors
```

I assumed that by 3rd element, you mean `index = 2`, change that accordingly

Comment: @KarthikRao but try to learn documentations. This is basic knowledge and highly duplicated on this page. Every book of C++ should teach you about this rather than asking questions here

Answer (score 0):

While you create an instance of your struct, the default constructor called. You can pass the 3rd element of the vector to the default constructor.

```
Req_Port reqPtr{colIndex.at(2),colIndex.at(2).size()};
```